# Python Pip Failing to work | What is going on?

Tags: python, pip

*Summary*

---

I've got the back end of a neat python program down, but I hate the gui options we have by default. Tkinter is unreliable, in my experience. And the turtle graphics thing would in no way benefit my project. So I looked into alternatives and Krivy came up. I followed the install step by step and I'm getting line after line of errors.

Windows 10

Python 3.6

*Question*

---

What is happening and how do I fix it? I've already looked at other questions and they are either from previous years or slightly different to my own problem. Below is the result of a pip install (or attempt).

*Outcome*

---

```
C:\Users\*>pip3.6 install pygyubu
Collecting pygyubu
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)': /simple/pygyubu/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)': /simple/pygyubu/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)': /simple/pygyubu/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)': /simple/pygyubu/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)': /simple/pygyubu/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pygyubu/:
  There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pygyubu/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygyubu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygyubu
```

P.S this isn't the true attempt, this is my last attempt, where I gave up on krivy and just wanted to know if it was working. I have tried absolutely every variation of the command. Nothing yields results.

Comment: Did you try anything from here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Comment: I have that open in one of my tabs, funnily enough. I've not had any luck with it.

Comment: try `pip3.6 install pygubu`

Comment: I have tried that, with no luck. I've gone through every variation of the command I could find. Nothing is working.

Comment: weird, i thought it was a typo on the package name (double check please). pygubu, not pygyubu

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libssl` (and maybe reinstall/rebuild python)

Comment: @Paolo But that should not result in a ssl error.

Comment: And yes, I have tried turning it off and on again too. And I have tried your suggestion previously, Mega.

Comment: Did you try updating ``pip``? What does `pip --version` return?

Comment: pip 9.0.3 is the version.

Comment: And if it was a typo in this one, that doesn't explain the other installs failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178045/discussion-between-megaing-and-john-smith).

Comment: Do you have either environment variable PIP_CERT or SSL_CERT_FILE ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure what that is, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pip install --egg pygubu`
and use "pip list --uptodate" and "pip list --outdated" command